# Poor query performance with index compared to without index

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance, query-performance

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and having a table partitioned by 'network_date' column of type DATE(every day has 
a partition, e.g., '2018-05-01', and each partition contains approximately 400,000 rows). The table has two compound indexes (not unique) which include the 'network_date' column as well (first in the order of 6 columns). The indexes are:

> 1. _daily_ad_level_demand_idx: network_date, publisher_network_id, display_advertiser_id, business_rule_id, campaign_id, ad_id
> 2. _daily_ad_level_supply_idx: network_date, publisher_network_id, publisher_id, widget_id

However, according to the EXPLAIN command, when running the following query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT 
    network_date,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_view, 0)) AS ad_view,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_spend_network, 0)) AS ad_spend_network,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_click, 0)) AS ad_click,
    campaign_id,
    display_advertiser_id,
    publisher_network_id,
    ad_id
FROM
    daily_ad_level
WHERE
    (publisher_network_id = 16020)
    AND network_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-04-15 00:00:00.000000',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-05-12 23:59:59.999000',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f')
GROUP BY campaign_id, network_date, display_advertiser_id, 
publisher_network_id, ad_id
```

no index is picked by the optimizer and a full table scan is taking place.
You can see the result here:
[EXPLAIN command output with 'network_date' included in index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7wnR.png)

After doing some research and puzzling over it, i have decided to remove 'network_date' column from the indexes - the partition pruning should do the necessary lookup anyway so it seems to be redundant to include it in the index. Running the EXPLAIN command again shows that now, an index is being chosen. You can see the result here: 
[EXPLAIN command output with **no** 'network_date' included in index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNFA3.png)

In terms of query duration, the performance was **decreased when an index was picked by the optimizer**: from 9.75 sec to 12.4 sec... The question is why???

Analyzing the **first** explain command output(the one with no index usage), one can see that 'filtered' and 'rows' columns have values of 50.00 and 4,474,281 respectively. Could it be that the optimizer inferred a full table scan is cheaper than using an index which would eliminate only about half the rows?
If so, i would expect the very same behavior in the second scenario, which is not the case: the optimizer chooses an index and the query performs poorly.

Does someone have any idea what may cause this behavior?

Comment: Guessing here: with `network_date` included the optimizer can see that your conditions are not very restrictive so it chooses the table scan.Without it, the optimizer sees that `publisher_network_id` is probably quite restrictive so it goes for the index approach even if in practical terms it is slower.

Comment: Can you show a `SHOW CREATE TABLE daily_ad_level`

Comment: @RaymondNijland create table script is too long... the table has like 500 partitions and 70 columns. I do think it's important to mention that the table has **no** primary key

Comment: I don't know on which engine the table is running.. But i do know not having a PRIMARY KEY on a InnoDB table is bad... Iám posting a little warning post of mine on dba stackexchange on why you should always have a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE key within a InnoDB table https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184

Comment: @RaymondNijland Forgot to mention: InnoDB storage engine

Comment: Is the table bigger than RAM?  Let's see RAM size and table size.

Comment: No PK?  InnoDB does not like you!

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments guys, it occurred to me that the **group by** order of columns affects the query performance significantly, that is, if I'm reordering the group by columns to match the index columns order (and adding an extra column that's currently missing in the query - business_rule_id) - the result is fetched in 0.23 sec, compared to 9.23 sec previously! Moreover, the optimizer chooses the right index this time. Here's the modified query:

```
SELECT 
    network_date,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_view, 0)) AS ad_view,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_spend_network, 0)) AS ad_spend_network,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_click, 0)) AS ad_click,
    campaign_id,
    display_advertiser_id,
    publisher_network_id,
    ad_id
FROM
    daily_ad_level
WHERE
    (publisher_network_id = 16020)
    AND network_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-04-15 00:00:00.000000',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-05-12 23:59:59.999000',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f')
    GROUP BY  network_date, publisher_network_id ,display_advertiser_id, 
    business_rule_id, campaign_id, ad_id ;
```

You can see the result screenshot here: [Optimized Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09NUX.png)

And here's the unoptimized result screenshot: [Unoptimized Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nepzT.png)

While the results aren't exactly the same (due to business_rule_id column addition to the group by clause), it still gives a good sense of the optimizer "way of thinking", so with the right adjustments, the required result could be achieved.

Great guidance guys, Thank you!

Comment: Which table is `business_rule_id` in?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with indexing the fields compared with an equality operator (=) first. Then, you should add the columns with the range operators (>, <, BETWEEN, ...). In this case, I don't see a reason to index the columns in the group by, as I don't think the optimizer will choose them. See the recommended index below.

Try to add this index:

```
ALTER TABLE `daily_ad_level` ADD INDEX `daily_ad_level_idx_id_date` (`publisher_network_id`,`network_date`);
```

Comment: " I don't see a reason to index the columns in the group by, as I don't think the optimizer will choose them" read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland, which part are you referring to? From my experience (and MySQL documentation states so as well), once you have a 'range' column in the index, there is no point in adding the columns from the GROUP BY clause, as they won't be used anyway.

Comment: Functions are not on the columns but on hard coded values which are then compared with column values,so it`s OK in this case.

Comment: if you don't optimize GROUP BY with indexes the MySQL optimizer will  always use a "file sort" or "temporary table" or resolve the results which is slow as hell with a large amounts of records..

Comment: @Mihai, thanks, I overlooked it somehow, even though I mentioned that, lol. Edited my answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, how would you suggest to do that in this case? Indexing both network_date and the columns from the group by won't be possible.

Comment: index `publisher_network_id, network_date`  and `campaign_id, network_date, display_advertiser_id, 
publisher_network_id, ad_id` ... Use a delivered table where you use the index `publisher_network_id, network_date` and self INNER JOIN the table on the PRIMARY KEY again so you can use the index `campaign_id, network_date, display_advertiser_id, 
publisher_network_id, ad_id` .. That should help..

Comment: @Tomer 'From my experience (and MySQL documentation states so as well), once you have a 'range' column in the index, there is no point in adding the columns from the GROUP BY clause, as they won't be used anyway' - did you refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#equality-range-optimization  ?
look for this text: 'For a BTREE index, an interval might be usable'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding two indexes and rewritting the query.

```
ALTER TABLE daily_ad_level
ADD INDEX daily_ad_level_idx_id_date (publisher_network_id, network_date);
```

And

```
ALTER TABLE daily_ad_level
ADD INDEX daily_ad_level_idx_campaign_id_network_date_display_advertiser_id_publisher_network_id_ad_id (campaign_id, network_date, display_advertiser_id, 
publisher_network_id, ad_id);
```

**Query rewrite**

i assume the column ad_id is the PRIMARY KEY in your table

```
SELECT
    network_date,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_view, 0)) AS ad_view,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_spend_network, 0)) AS ad_spend_network,
    SUM(COALESCE(ad_click, 0)) AS ad_click,
    campaign_id,
    display_advertiser_id,
    publisher_network_id,
    ad_id
FROM (

    SELECT
     ad_id
    FROM  
     daily_ad_level
    WHERE
          publisher_network_id = 16020
        AND
          network_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-04-15 00:00:00.000000',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-05-12 23:59:59.999000',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') 
    ) AS daily_ad_level_filterd

    INNER JOIN 
     daily_ad_level
    ON
     daily_ad_level_filterd.ad_id = daily_ad_level.ad_id 

    GROUP BY 
      campaign_id, network_date, display_advertiser_id, 
    publisher_network_id, ad_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 - better index**

Don't start the indexes with `network_date`, end them with it.  Why?  Generally, once you hit a "range" test, you cannot use more columns of an index.

Your first query needs just

```
INDEX(publisher_network_id, network_date)  -- in this order
```

When Optimizing tables that are larger than can be cached in RAM (the buffer_pool), the overwhelming consideration is disk hits.  This index minimizes the number of disk hits.

Unrelated:  I see no need for wrapping the datetimes in `STR_TO_DATE`.

**Step 2 - toss partitioning *if* not needed**

Are you using `PARTITIONs` for some reason?

- Performance -- not likely to help; certainly not better than the `INDEX` I just recommended.
- Purging old records -- a very good reason.

I can't analyze the rest of your query since there is no clue of which table each column is in.  If, for example, the `GROUP BY` columns are not all in a single table, there is *no way* to use an index for that.

If you have more than about 50 partitions in the table, you are reaching into other inefficiencies.  Recommend switching to weekly or monthly partitions in this case.

Are there other queries that we should consider?

**Step 3 - better clustered PRIMARY KEY**

- Get rid of partitioning (unless you need it for purging), and
- Make the `PRIMARY KEY` *start with* `(publisher_network_id, network_date)`.  (Tack on an `id` or whatever is necessary to make it unique, since the PK must be unique.)

Why would this be even better?  Then all the rows necessary are *consecutive* ("clustered") together, thereby minimizing the number of disk hits.

Sure, there will then be a temp table, sort, etc, for the `GROUP BY`, but this might actually happen in RAM.

**Step 4 - Summary table**

Data Warehousing involves "reports".  They are very costly to extract from the raw data because of how many rows need to be read.  Build and maintain a Summary Table that has row(s) for each combination of keys for each, say, day.  Then run the 'report' against that table; it may run 10 *times* as fast.

More on summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables